# Getting list of string(Collection) from an object using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class as following

```
Class Department {
    private String departmentName;
    private List<String> students;
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

Now i want to fetch students attribute (`List<String>`) only from Department class but not entire Department object with restriction departName := Chemistry.

How to write hibernate criteria for this???

Comment: yes. But my questions is will Projections.property("students") will return list<String>?

Comment: I have same requirement..but not getting from anywhere.. :(

Answer (score 0):

About you question: no, this projection is not possible because collection of elements has the same lifecycle of owner entity
Getting collections of elements with criteria is not possibile (read [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Embedded_Collections)). You have to work with native SQL to return `List<String>`.